# problem about Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

suppose we need to prove$|(0,1)|=|(0,1]|$

First, $x\in(0,1)$,

$(0,1)→(0,1]$, $f(x)=x$,injective

$x∈(0,1]$

$(0,1]→(0,1)$, $g(x)=\frac{x}{2}$, injective

So according to sb theorem,$(0,1)↔(0,1]$ is bjective,but $0.6$ is not covered by $g(x)$ so it is not subjective and not bijective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem says that if there are injective maps $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ then there exists some bijection between $A$ and $B$. It doesn't say that the specific maps $f$ and $g$ are bijections. (and in your example $f$ and $g$ are indeed not bijections)

Comment: Thanks,but does it prove that  $|(0,1)|=|(0,1]|$?

Comment: Yes, it does, exactly by CSB theorem. It tells us there is a bijection between these sets  which exactly means $|(0,1)|=|(0,1]|$. That's the good thing about this theorem, it gives us a way to prove two sets have the same cardinality without actually finding a specific bijection between them.